# Getting Lasso to work correctly on subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a scatter plot matrix which will be composed by some subplots. I have extracted from a .txt file my data and created an array of shape `(x,y,z,p1,p2,p3,p4)`. The first three columns of the array represent the x,y,z coordinates from the original image that these data come from and the last four columns (p1, p2, p3, p4) some other parameters. Consequently, in each row of the array the parameters p1, p2, p3, p4 have the same coordinates(x,y,z).In the scatter plot, I want to visualize each p_i(e.g. p1) parameter against the other p_i(e.g. p2, p3, p4) parameters.

I want to draw a region of interest(ROI) in every subplot, highlight the points that are included in the ROI in every subplot. In each subplot different parameters are visualized(e.g. p1 vs p2) but for one point in each subplot there is another point with the same x, y, z coordinates in the rest subplots. I implemented the drawing of the ROI by using the `matplotlib` example [Lasso](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/lasso_demo.html). An example of what this code implements is shown in the following figure. [image: Figure 1]

There is a malfunction in my implementation. I can draw lassos in every subplot, but points are highlighted only, when a lasso is drawn in specific subplot which corresponds to the first call of the `LassoManager` function in my code( in my code `selector1`). As it can be seen in the next figure, an initial value is given to lassos that can be drawn in the different subplots, but only the id that corresponds in selector 1 is used causing the malfunction of the code, independently in which subplot I drew a ROI.

[image: Figure 2]

Here is my code:

```
"""
Show how to use a lasso to select a set of points and get the indices
of the selected points.  A callback is used to change the color of the
selected points

This is currently a proof-of-concept implementation (though it is
usable as is).  There will be some refinement of the API.
"""


from matplotlib.widgets import Lasso
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
from matplotlib.collections import RegularPolyCollection
from matplotlib import path


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Datum(object):
      colorin = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
      colorout = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')
      def __init__(self, x, y, include=False):
          self.x = x
          self.y = y
          if include: self.color = self.colorin
          else: self.color = self.colorout

class LassoManager(object):
    #class for highlighting region of points within a Lasso
      def __init__(self, ax, data):


          self.axes = ax
          self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
          self.data = data
          self.Nxy = len(data)

          facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
          self.xys = [(d.x, d.y) for d in data]
          fig = ax.figure
          self.collection = RegularPolyCollection(
             fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(1,),
             facecolors=facecolors,
             offsets = self.xys,
             transOffset = ax.transData)

          ax.add_collection(self.collection)

          self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)

      def callback(self, verts):
          facecolors = self.collection.get_facecolors()
          print "The id of this lasso is", id(self)


          p = path.Path(verts)
          ind = p.contains_points(self.xys)
          #ind prints boolean array of points in subplot where true means that the point is included

          for i in range(len(self.xys)):


              if ind[i]:

                # facecolors[i] = Datum.colorin
                axes[0][0].plot(x[i], y[i], 'ro',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[2][0].plot(x[i], y1[i], 'ro',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[1][0].plot(x[i], x1[i], 'ro',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[1][4].plot(y[i], x1[i], 'ro',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[2][5].plot(x1[i], y1[i], 'ro',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[2][6].plot(y[i], y1[i], 'ro',  ls='',  picker=3)
                # print ind[i], x[i], y[i], x1[i], y1[i]

              else:

                # facecolors[i] = Datum.colorout
                axes[0][0].plot(x[i], y[i], 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[2][0].plot(x[i], y1[i], 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[1][0].plot(x[i], x1[i], 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[1][7].plot(y[i], x1[i], 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[2][8].plot(x1[i], y1[i], 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
                axes[2][9].plot(y[i], y1[i], 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)

          plt.draw()


          self.canvas.draw_idle()
          self.canvas.widgetlock.release(self.lasso)
          del self.lasso
          # noinspection PyArgumentList


      def onpress(self, event):
          if self.canvas.widgetlock.locked(): return
          if event.inaxes is None: return

          self.lasso = Lasso(event.inaxes, (event.xdata, event.ydata), self.callback)

          # acquire a lock on the widget drawing
          self.canvas.widgetlock(self.lasso)




if __name__ == '__main__':

   dat = np.loadtxt(r"parameters.txt")
   x, y = dat[:, 3], dat[:, 4]  #p1,p2
   x1, y1 = dat[:, 5], dat[:, 6]  #p3,p4

   a = np.array([x,y])  #p1,p2
   a = a.transpose()

   b = np.array([x,y1])  #p1,p4
   b = b.transpose()

   c = np.array([x,x1])  #p1,p3
   c = c.transpose()

   d = np.array([y,x1])  #p3,p2
   d = d.transpose()

   e = np.array([x1,y1])  #p3,p4
   e = e.transpose()

   f = np.array([y,y1])  ##p2, p4
   f = f.transpose()


   data = []

   data0 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in a]   #p1,p2
   data.append(data0)
   data1 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in b]   #p1,p4
   data.append(data1)
   data2 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in c]   #p1,p3
   data.append(data2)
   data3 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in d]   #p3,p2
   data.append(data3)
   data4 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in e]   #p3,p4
   data.append(data4)
   data5 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in f]   #p2, p4
   data.append(data5)

   #print data
   #print len(data)

   fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=3)

   axes[0][0].plot(x, y, 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
   axes[0][0].set_xlabel('p1')
   axes[0][0].set_ylabel('p2')
   axes[0][0].set_xlim((min(x)-50, max(x)+50))
   axes[0][0].set_ylim((min(y)-50, max(y)+50))
   selector1 = LassoManager(axes[0][0], data[0])
   print "selector1 is", id(selector1)      #lman.append(l1)

   #p1 vs p4
   axes[2][0].plot(x, y1, 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
   axes[2][0].set_xlabel('p1')
   axes[2][0].set_ylabel('p4')
   axes[2][0].set_xlim((min(x)-50, max(x)+50))
   axes[2][0].set_ylim((min(y1)-40, max(y1)+50))
   selector2 = LassoManager(axes[2][0], data[1])
   print "selector2 is", id(selector2)


   #p1 vs p3
   axes[1][0].plot(x, x1, 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
   axes[1][0].set_xlabel('p1')
   axes[1][0].set_ylabel('p3')
   axes[1][0].set_xlim((min(x)-50, max(x)+50))
   axes[1][0].set_ylim((min(x1)-40, max(x1)+50))
   selector3 = LassoManager(axes[1][0], data[2])
   print "selector3 is", id(selector3)

   #p2 vs p3
   axes[1][10].plot(y, x1, 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
   axes[1][11].set_xlabel('p2')
   axes[1][12].set_ylabel('p3')
   axes[1][13].set_xlim((min(y)-50, max(y)+50))
   axes[1][14].set_ylim((min(x1)-40, max(x1)+50))
   selector4 =  LassoManager(axes[1][15], data[3])
   print "selector4 is", id(selector4)




   #p2 vs p4
   axes[2][16].plot(y, y1, 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
   axes[2][17].set_xlabel('p2')
   axes[2][18].set_ylabel('p4')
   axes[2][19].set_xlim((min(y)-50, max(y)+50))
   axes[2][20].set_ylim((min(y1)-40, max(y1)+50))
   selector5 = LassoManager(axes[2][21], data[5])
   print "selector5 is", id(selector5)


   #p3 vs p4
   axes[2][22].plot(x1, y1, 'bo',  ls='',  picker=3)
   axes[2][23].set_xlabel('p3')
   axes[2][24].set_ylabel('p4')
   axes[2][25].set_xlim((min(x1)-50, max(x1)+50))
   axes[2][26].set_ylim((min(y1)-40, max(y1)+50))
   selector6 = LassoManager(axes[2][27], data[4])
   print "selector6 is", id(selector6)


   #non-visible subplots
   axes[0][28].plot(x,x)
   axes[0][29].set_visible(False)
   axes[0][30].plot(y,y)
   axes[0][31].set_visible(False)
   axes[1][32].plot(x1,x1)
   axes[1][33].set_visible(False)

   plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.95, wspace=0.6, hspace=0.7)

   plt.show()
```

Why does this happen in my code? There is no error in the code, but it does not work correctly. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Is this an interactive plot? If not I don't understand why you're using the Lasso manager to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, it is! Firstly, I draw a lasso in a subplot and then the points that are included in it are highlighted in all subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as far as I can tell is that on each `init` you're replacing the `button_press_event` of the canvas with a new one.

Most likely you need to handle all axes with one `button_press_event` callback (as they all interact via the same canvas object).

**FIX**

Below is a functioning example, based on the official lasso example in the docs.

The approach I tried is to create just one `LassoManager` (as it interacts with just one canvas per figure) but let the axis, data, etc be lists for each subplot.

Then the callback accesses the `current_axis` member to determine which axis is currently active.

```
"""
Show how to use a lasso to select a set of points and get the indices
of the selected points.  A callback is used to change the color of the
selected points

This is currently a proof-of-concept implementation (though it is
usable as is).  There will be some refinement of the API.
"""
from matplotlib.widgets import Lasso
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
from matplotlib.collections import RegularPolyCollection
from matplotlib import path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import nonzero
from numpy.random import rand

class Datum(object):
    colorin = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
    colorout = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')
    def __init__(self, x, y, include=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if include: self.color = self.colorin
        else: self.color = self.colorout


class LassoManager(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, data):
        self.axes = [ax]
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.data = [data]

        self.Nxy = [ len(data) ]

        facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
        self.xys = [ [(d.x, d.y) for d in data] ]
        fig = ax.figure
        self.collection = [ RegularPolyCollection(
            fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(100,),
            facecolors=facecolors,
            offsets = self.xys[0],
            transOffset = ax.transData)]

        ax.add_collection(self.collection[0])

        self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)

    def callback(self, verts):

        axind = self.axes.index(self.current_axes)
        facecolors = self.collection[axind].get_facecolors()
        p = path.Path(verts)
        ind = p.contains_points(self.xys[axind])
        for i in range(len(self.xys[axind])):
            if ind[i]:
                facecolors[i] = Datum.colorin
            else:
                facecolors[i] = Datum.colorout

        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.canvas.widgetlock.release(self.lasso)
        del self.lasso

    def onpress(self, event):
        if self.canvas.widgetlock.locked(): return
        if event.inaxes is None: return
        self.current_axes = event.inaxes

        self.lasso = Lasso(event.inaxes, (event.xdata, event.ydata), self.callback)
        # acquire a lock on the widget drawing
        self.canvas.widgetlock(self.lasso)

    def add_axis(self, ax,  data):
        self.axes.append(ax)
        self.data.append(data)

        self.Nxy.append( len(data) )

        facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
        self.xys.append( [(d.x, d.y) for d in data] )
        fig = ax.figure
        self.collection.append( RegularPolyCollection(
            fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(100,),
            facecolors=facecolors,
            offsets = self.xys[-1],
            transOffset = ax.transData))

        ax.add_collection(self.collection[-1])



if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = [Datum(*xy) for xy in rand(100, 2)]
    data2 = [Datum(*xy) for xy in rand(100, 2)]

    ax = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    lman = LassoManager(ax, data)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    lman.add_axis(ax2, data2)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What does exactly the `add_axis` function do in your example code? Probably, the almost correct you mentioned in your answer, has to do with the fact that in the right subplot are not highlighted the correct points when you draw a lasso.

Comment: @user3204834: It adds the axis, collections, etc information to the LassoManager, so that when that specific axis is clicked the Lasso uses the data for that axis.

Comment: @user3204834: I fixed the issue: I'd forgotten to access the last element of `xys`, i.e. `self.xys[-1]` in `add_axis`.

Comment: I adjusted your answer to my requirements. It works perfectly. I was stuck in this  for around a month,because I was not aware of how exactly matplotlib's properties work. Thank you very much for your help.